# Appcelerator. Sending XHR batch requests

Tags: batch-file, appcelerator-mobile

Titanium SDK version: 1.6.2
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am developing an iOS app in Appcelerator. In this app I am getting all the users facebook friends and send them (all) to my API (built in Rails3). If a user got alot of friends this requests takes a long time and time out sometimes.

How can I alter my code so that I can send the facebook friend ids in "batches"?

This is my code: http://pastie.org/2043126

Thankful for all input!

Comment: how many ids are you talking about sending?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the response from Facebook, parse it and store the ids in an array.
Loop through the array, pop X ids, and ApiPOST them.
At the end of the onload function for this request, get the next X items until the array is empty.
When the array is empty do the table.setData().

You can also launch multiple xhr requests at the same time using different xhr objects.  In one of my Appcelerator apps, I have a pool of 10 xhr requests caching images at the same time.

Comment: Sounds like a good way, but isn´t it "costly" to do a request for each "friend". I do not think I can do it because I need my API to return the contacts in an alphabetical order.